# Using an internal signal in a testbench

Tags: vhdl, testbench

I am using **HDL Designer** and have a pretty large design I need to test. I have created a test bench by using HDL Designer itself and did not do it standalone.
Like the title states, I want to know how to use an internal signal to my advantage, for example do *if* conditions using such a signal.

Now, I have found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286725/how-can-i-get-internal-signals-to-testbench-in-vhdl-97-and-isim

But I don't know how to use a package in HDL Designer, or how to do step 2 in the above link.

The reason I need to use an internal signal is mainly because I have a state machine and I want to perform actions based on the current state.

The VHDL standard I'm using is VHDL 93. I'm stating this because I saw solutions using VHDL 2008 but it's not applicable to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Jim's answer is spot on. HDL Designer does support packages, or certainly used to(IIRC). Failing that, bring out another port with the extra info on it. (Then hide that port by instantiating the DUT in a wrapper entity, that doesn't bring out the diagnostics for synthesis purposes)

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks for your answer, I really preferred to avoid using a port, because I may need to use other signals all of a sudden, or maybe not use them, and I don't want to constantly create/delete ports. Also, I need to read the *current_state* signal, and I'm not sure how to output it using a port (I'm using the graphical state machine feature, so I can't insert my own code or anything).

Comment: VHDL -2008 can be viewed as a superset of -1993 except shared variables (changed in -2002) and most designs could be *analyzed* (compiled) into a reference library used by a -2008 simulator supporting external names. Elaboration order requires your design be elaborated before the external name is used in a declaration or concurrent statement in your testbench, generally implying the external name is evaluated in a concurrent statement after the component instantiation of the design top. Concurrent statements are elaborated in the order they appear.

Comment: Some -2008 simulators can allow -1993 shared variables. The overlap in the set of those that can and that also support external names isn't readily clear. Some verification packages may support the use of VHPI/VPI etc. to allow access in lieu of external names.